# adding <path> to iframe run time

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, charts

I Have an iframe chart from some website and all I wanna do is to add a horizontal line throw the chart. I add some JS but it does not take effects. I wonder if someone can help me with that.
this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame" width="450" height="260" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/507016/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&title=Height+Level+River+%28Murazzi+Po%29&type=line&xaxis=Time+&yaxis=Measured+Height+%28+m+%29"></iframe>
</body>


</html>
```

and this is the JS that help me to inject

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $iframe = $('#frame');

$iframe.ready(function() {

    setTimeout( function(){ 

    $iframe.contents().find(".highcharts-series-group").append('<path fill="none" d="M 62 132.5 L 415 132.5" stroke="#010" stroke-width="1" zIndex="1" opacity="1"></path>');

  }  , 3000 );



</script>
```

I wait 3 seconds to ensure that iframe loads completely.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't access a cross origin iframe due to ***[same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)***. For same domain iframe use load event of iframe....not `ready`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. so you mean I cant do such a thing?